# symfony 2.3 how to access the entity object inside a form handler?

Tags: php, symfony

I am having an issue on symfony 2.3 project. This issue is inside a form handler. How can I retrieve the entity object to persist it ? I tryed the '$this->form->getData();' method but it throws this error : " EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given. "
Here the code, I use :

```
<?php

namespace Foobar\CarBundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CarHandler {
    protected $request;
    protected $form;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, EntityManager $em) {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Process form
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function process() {
        if ('POST' == $this->request->getMethod()) {
            $this->form->handleRequest($this->request);
            $data = $this->form->getData();
            $this->onSuccess($data);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function onSuccess($entity) {
        //pb here :  EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given. 
        //how to access object ???
        $this->em->persist($entity);                      

        $this->em->flush();                                          
    }

}
```

the enity :

```
<?php



namespace Foobar\CarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Car
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foobar\CarBundle\Entity\CarRepository")
 */
class Car
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="brand", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="color", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $color;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="power", type="integer")
     */
    private $power;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Car
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set brand
     *
     * @param string $brand
     * @return Car
     */
    public function setBrand($brand)
    {
        $this->brand = $brand;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get brand
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBrand()
    {
        return $this->brand;
    }

    /**
     * Set color
     *
     * @param string $color
     * @return Car
     */
    public function setColor($color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get color
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }

    /**
     * Set power
     *
     * @param integer $power
     * @return Car
     */
    public function setPower($power)
    {
        $this->power = $power;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get power
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPower()
    {
        return $this->power;
    }
}
```

the formtype :

```
    <?php

namespace Foobar\CarBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class CarType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('name', null);
        $builder->add('brand', null);
        $builder->add('power', null);
        $builder->add('color', null);

        $builder->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'car';
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your `Form` class, your request data and your entity class.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony2 you don' have to process the form through an handler you can directly process it in the controller where you action is defined, this is a simpler way to code and to avoid mistakes ...

here is an example of an action using a form in a controller :

```
<?php 

   namespace Acme\BlogBundle\controller;

   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
   use Acme\BlogBundle\Form\UserType;

   class DefaultController extends Controller
   {

          public function defaultAction()
          {
               $entity                       = new Entity();
               $form                         = $this->createForm( new EntityType(), $entity);

               $request                        = $this->get( 'request' );

              if ( $request->getMethod() == 'POST' )
              {
                 $form->bind( $request );
                 $em                         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                 if ( $form->isValid() ) {
                     $em->persist($feedback);
                     $em->flush();
                 }
              }             

         return $this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Default:default.html.twig', array(  'someValues' => $someValues, 'form' => $form->createView() ));
       }

   }
```

i'm passing my oject entity to be saved directly in the form with the $this->createForm() so when the form is submitted and granted ( with assetic or if all the required input are filled ) the object entity is filled with form values and ready to be persisted and flushed .

you can always update or modify values of this object with $entity->setVARIABLE() before to persist it .

And if , for some specific reason, you still need to access POST and / or GET values directly , you can use :

```
  //GET
  $request->query->get('foo');
  //POST
  $request->request->get('bar');
```

Comment: But let's say I am overriding FOS Message form handler and I don't want to override the controller... How to get the EM in the handler ?